# ZIP archive cannot close after new zip in foreach (PHP)

Tags: php, zip

PHP-Version: 8

My script gets pathes to adding the files in a zip. After an individual size, the zip closed and a new one opened for adding files. All works, but when the second file should closed, i'll get an error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in...`

Everything is ok in my log file. The first ZIP is created, files are added and closed. Then the 2nd ZIP is created, files are added and then the ZIP should be closed again. The error comes when closing the second file.

Thats my script:

```
/**
 * check and process file list
**/
    ## log
    $log->logging($lf, "Check backuppathes list.");
    
    ## check file list
    if(!empty($fullfilelist)) {
        
        ## log
        $log->logging($lf, "Setting zip parameter.");
        
        ## zip counter
        $zc = 0;
        
        ## zip size
        $zs = 0;
        
        ## zip path
        $zp = (addslashes(__DIR__))."\\zip\\";
        
        ## zipfile
        $zipfile = $zp.date("Y-m-d")."-".str_pad($zc, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).".zip";
        
        ## log
        $log->logging($lf, "Create zip file: ".$zipfile);
        
        ## start zip file
        $myzip[$zc] = new mfzip;
        $myzip[$zc]->newzip($zipfile);
        
        ## check new zip file
        if($myzip[$zc]->result == 200) {
            
            ## log
            $log->logging($lf, "Zip ".$zipfile." starts! Set password...");
            
            ## set zip password
            $myzip[$zc]->passzip($CFG['zippass']);
            
            ## check setting
            if($myzip[$zc]->result == 200) {
                
                ## log
                $log->logging($lf, "Password set! Process pathes...");
                
                ## process file list
                foreach($fullfilelist as $ffl) {
                    
                    ## local file
                    $l = $ffl;
                    
                    ## log
                    $log->logging($lf, "Add local file: ".$l);
                    
                    ## file in zip
                    $r = substr($ffl, 3, 10000000000);
                    
                    ## checking file reading
                    if(is_readable($l)) {
                    
                        ## add file
                        $myzip[$zc]->add($l, $r);
                        
                        ## check adding
                        if($myzip[$zc]->result == 200) {
                            
                            ## log
                            $log->logging($lf, "Adding successful! Crypt file...");
                            
                            ## crypt file
                            $myzip[$zc]->cf($r);
                            
                            ## check crypt
                            if($myzip[$zc]->result == 200) {
                                
                                ## log
                                $log->logging($lf, "Crypting successful! Get stats of file...");
                                
                                ## get file stats
                                $myzip[$zc]->stats($r);
                            
                                ## check stats
                                if($myzip[$zc]->result == 200 && is_array($myzip[$zc]->fstats)) {
                                    
                                    ## log
                                    $log->logging($lf, "Get stats successful! Checking zip size...");
                                    
                                    ## filesize
                                    $rfs = $myzip[$zc]->fstats['size'];
                                    
                                    ## new zip size
                                    $zs = $zs + $rfs;
                                    
                                    ## log
                                    $log->logging($lf, "File in zip: ".$rfs." bytes | current zip size: ".$zs." bytes");
                                    
                                    ## check zip size with configured size
                                    if($zs > $CFG['zipsize']) {
                                        
                                        ## log
                                        $log->logging($lf, "Close zip and start new file (".$zc.")!");
                                        
                                        ## close zip
                                        $myzip[$zc]->cz();
                                        
                                        ## check closing
                                        if($myzip[$zc]->result == 200) {
                                            
                                            ## log
                                            $log->logging($lf, "Closing successfully: ".$zipfile);
                                            
                                            ## counting up
                                            $zc++;
                                            
                                            ## zipfile
                                            $zipfile = $zp.date("Y-m-d")."-".str_pad($zc, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).".zip";
                                            
                                            ## start new zip file
                                            $myzip[$zc] = new mfzip;
                                            $myzip[$zc]->newzip($zipfile);
                                            
                                            ## check new file
                                            if($myzip[$zc]->result == 200) {
                                                
                                                ## log
                                                $log->logging($lf, "Create new zip file: ".$zipfile);
                                                
                                            }
                                        
                                            ## set zip size to 0
                                            $zs = 0;
                                            
                                        } else {
                                            
                                            ## log
                                            $log->logging($lf, "ERROR: Closing error: ".$zipfile);
                                            break;
                                            
                                        }
                                        
                                    }
                                    
                                } else {
                                    
                                    ## log
                                    $log->logging($lf, "ERROR: Can't get stats of file ".$r);
                                    
                                }
                                
                            } else {
                                
                                ## log
                                $log->logging($lf, "ERROR: Can't crypt file: ".$r);
                                
                            }
                            
                        } else {
                                
                            ## log
                            $log->logging($lf, "ERROR: Can't adding file: ".$r);
                            
                        }
                        
                    } else {
                        
                        ## log
                        $log->logging($lf, "ERROR: Can't read file: ".$l);
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            } else {
                
                ## log
                $log->logging($lf, "ERROR: Can't set password for zip file: ".$zipfile);
                
            }
            
            ## log
            $log->logging($lf, "Last closing file: ".$zipfile);
            
            ## close zip
            $myzip[$zc]->cz();
            
            ## check closing
            if($myzip[$zc]->result == 200) {
                
                ## log
                $log->logging($lf, "Closing successfully!");
                
            } else {
                
                ## log
                $log->logging($lf, "ERROR: Closing error: ".$zipfile);
                
            }
            
        } else {
            
            ## log
            $log->logging($lf, "ERROR: Creating zip file: ".$zipfile);
            
        }
        
    } else {
        
        ## log
        $log->logging($lf, "ERROR: No backup pathes!");
        
    }
```

Thats my zip class:

```
/**
 * marcfunk zipping class
**/
    class mfzip {
        
        ## vars
        public $fstats;
        public $result;
        public $zip;
        
        
        /**
         * create zip archive
         * @param: string, filename of zipfile
        **/
            public function newzip($filename = "") {
                
                ## check filename
                if($filename !== "") {
                
                    ## start zip class
                    $newzip = new ZipArchive();
                    
                    ## create archive
                    if($newzip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
                        
                        ## status code
                        $this->result = 200;
                        
                        ## zip class
                        $this->zip = $newzip;
                        
                    } else {
                        
                        $this->result = 900;
                        
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    
                    $this->result = 900;
                    
                }
                
            }
        
        
        
        /**
         * set zip password
         * @param: string, password for zip
        **/
            public function passzip($hash) {
                
                $setpass = $this->zip;
                if($setpass->setPassword($hash)) {
                    
                    $this->result = 200;
                    
                } else {
                    
                    $this->result = 900;
                    
                }
                
            }
        
        
        
        /**
         * add file to archive
         * @param: string, path to local file
         * @param: string, path in zip file
        **/
            public function add($local = "", $remote = "") {
                
                $addfile = $this->zip;
                
                ## check local
                if($local !== "" && file_exists($local)) {
                    
                    ## check remote
                    if($remote !== "") {
                        
                        ## add file
                        if($addfile->addFile($local, $remote)) {
                            
                            $this->result = 200;
                            
                        } else {
                            
                            $this->result = 900;
                            
                        }
                        
                    } else {
                        
                        $this->result = 900;
                        
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    
                    $this->result = 900;
                    
                }
                
            }
        
        
        
        /**
         * crypt file
         * @param: string, path in zip file
        **/
            public function cf($remote = "") {
                
                $encr = $this->zip;
                
                ## check remote
                if($remote !== "") {
                    
                    ## crypt file
                    if($encr->setEncryptionName($remote, ZipArchive::EM_AES_256)) {
                        
                        $this->result = 200;
                        
                    } else {
                    
                        $this->result = 900;
                        
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    
                    $this->result = 900;
                    
                }
                
            }
        
        
        
        /**
         * stats of file
         * @param: string, path in zip file
        **/
            public function stats($remote = "") {
                
                $stats = $this->zip;
                
                ## check remote
                if($remote !== "") {
                    
                    ## stats of file
                    if($this->fstats = $stats->statName($remote)) {
                        
                        ## result
                        $this->result = 200;
                        
                    } else {
                    
                        $this->result = 900;
                        
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    
                    $this->result = 900;
                    
                }
                
            }
        
        
        
        /**
         * close zip
        **/
            public function cz() {
                
                if($this->zip->close() === TRUE) {
                    
                    $this->result = 200;
                    
                } else {
                    
                    $this->result = 900;
                    
                }
                
            }
        
    }
```

I checked up, that the files are available and readable. I have also code a pause after the first close and before starting the second file. The first zip is okay and can extract, but he won't create the second file.

Comment: Sounds like you might be trying to close the same zip file more than once ...? You got `$myzip[$zc]->cz();` inside your foreach loop, and another `$myzip[$zc]->cz();` after it. Sure those have not executed with the same value of `$zf`?

Comment: Although not wrong, deeply nested code can be very hard to read. There’s a pattern called “return early” which can fix this. Here’s one method rewritten in that pattern which I personally think is much easier to read, and I don’t think needs comments even since the methods and variables are all obvious enough. (Unique error codes or messages would make this so much easier to debug, however.) https://3v4l.org/f9m4J

Comment: At this line "if($zs > $CFG['zipsize']) {" i checked the size. The limit is i. e. 5 mb. After reaching the limit, the zip closed with $myzip[$zc]->cz(); and if the result is 200, a new zip starts. At the first round he starts zip001.zip, add files and close the file (the file is correctly created). After that, he starts zip002.zip, set the sizecounter to zero and add files (all with result = 200). When he reached again the limit, he should close the zip and starts again,...the second close failed, he only writes the 001.zip and breaked at the 002.zip.